# How to choose the aggregate root in this scenario?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, aggregate, domain-driven-design

I have 4 entities:

- Movie
- Scheduled movie
- Ticket
- TicketReservation
  Here is the er diagram:
  [Er diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9sfYB.png)

I designed the aggregate roots as follows:

Movie with entity scheduled movie
TicketReservation with entity ticket

The problem is, the relationship between Ticket and Scheduled movie. How do I do it without breaking the rule of "an aggregate can only be referenced from the outside through its root"?

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Ticket to refer to a scheduled movie, then ScheduledMovie (or perhaps Showing better fits the ubiquitous language?) wants to be its own aggregate root.

So you'd have

- Reservation holds entity Ticket
- Ticket refers to ScheduledMovie/Showing
- ScheduledMovie/Showing refers to Movie

Comment: Okay, but the communication between ScheduledMovie/Showing and Movie needs to happen in one transaction.